# Opnsense Wireguard Site-to-Site VPN. Don't see Windows clients

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn, wireguard, opnsense

I need to make a transparent Site-to-site VPN between 2 Opnsense routers.

As I don't have admin skills I followed this tutorial https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-set-up-wireguard-in-opnsense/ I did exactly same steps, so I will not duplicate them here.

As the result the tunnel is up and running, but I see (IP scanner) and have access (can login by SSH) only to my Linux (Ubuntu) machines from both sides, and don't see and don't have access to Windows machines.

Comment: What does *don't see* and *have access to* mean? How do you test it? How is things configured? Show us your config; don't point at a tutorial.

Comment: @vidarlo - he said he did exactly what is in the tutorial :p anyway, since some (more than 1 since he says machines) computers are accessible through wireguard, you would assume wireguard itself is not the issue, the issue is probably with the Windows machines, most likely a firewall issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Assumptions is the mother of all fuckups.

Comment: @JaromandaX disabling firewall on Windows machines helps, thank you. I think I should Google something related to NAT and Masquerade, probably. I used to use an OpenVPN tunel and din't have such problems.